# PUT request resulted in 500 (Server Error); invoking error handler

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, resttemplate

## Method to update metadata info of my model through Rest client

my requirement is to do a PUT operation based on a key,along ith this i am sending request parameter for my model which is ProjectMetadata here.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/di/v1/app/{projectKey}/metadata", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<?> updateProject(@PathVariable(value = "projectKey") 
String projectKey,
        @RequestBody ProjectMetadata metadata) throws JSONException {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic <aut key>");

    JSONObject requestBody = new JSONObject();
    requestBody.put("label", metadata.getLabel());
    requestBody.put("description", metadata.getDescription());
    requestBody.put("shortDesc", metadata.getShortDesc());
    requestBody.put("tag", metadata.getTags());
    logger.debug("requestBody" + requestBody);

    HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(requestBody.toString(), headers);
    logger.debug("requestentity" + requestEntity.toString());

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String url = "http://<>/public/api/projects/{projectKey}/metadata";
    logger.debug("trying to send request to create project");
    ResponseEntity<?> createResponse = null;

    try {
        createResponse = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.PUT, requestEntity, String.class, projectKey);
        // restTemplate.put(url, requestEntity,projectKey);
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {

        logger.error("Exceptions occurred while processing the request::");
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(e.getResponseBodyAsString(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    return createResponse;
}
```

### ProjectMetadata Model

```
public class ProjectMetadata 
{
   private String label;
   private String description;
   private String shortDesc;
   private List<String> tags;

   public ProjectMetadata() {
       super();
   }
   public ProjectMetadata(String label, String description, String shortDesc, List<String> tags) {
       super();
       this.label = label;
       this.description = description;
       this.shortDesc = shortDesc;
       this.tags = tags;
   }
   public String getLabel() {
       return label;
   }
   public void setLabel(String label) {
       this.label = label;
   }
   public String getDescription() {
       return description;
   }
   public void setDescription(String description) {
       this.description = description;
   }
   public String getShortDesc() {
       return shortDesc;
   }
   public void setShortDesc(String shortDesc) {
       this.shortDesc = shortDesc;
   }
   public List<String> getTags() {
       return tags;
   }
   public void setTags(List<String> tags) {
       this.tags = tags;
   }
```

}

## error stack

```
>2018-04-10 11:48:00,342 11345 [http-nio-9080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils - Failed to meta-introspect annotation [interface org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody]: java.lang.NullPointerException
2018-04-10 11:48:00,350 11353 [http-nio-9080-exec-1] DEBUG c.p.controller.ProjectController - requestBody{"description":"adsfy","shortDesc":"nsfdf","label":"testapp","tag":["tag12"]}
2018-04-10 11:48:00,354 11357 [http-nio-9080-exec-1] DEBUG c.p.controller.ProjectController - requestentity<{"description":"adsfy","shortDesc":"nsfdf","label":"testapp","tag":["tag12"]},{Content-Type=[application/json], Authorization=[Basic <>]}>
2018-04-10 11:48:00,366 11369 [http-nio-9080-exec-1] DEBUG c.p.controller.ProjectController - trying to send request to create project
2018-04-10 11:48:00,394 11397 [http-nio-9080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.client.RestTemplate - Created PUT request for "http://<>/public/api/projects/abcde/metadata"
2018-04-10 11:48:00,394 11397 [http-nio-9080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.client.RestTemplate - Setting request Accept header to [text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*]
2018-04-10 11:48:00,394 11397 [http-nio-9080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.client.RestTemplate - Writing [{"description":"adsfy","shortDesc":"nsfdf","label":"testapp","tag":["tag12"]}] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@6c0f36de]
2018-04-10 11:48:00,954 11957 [http-nio-9080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.client.RestTemplate - PUT request for "http://<>/public/api/projects/abcde/metadata" resulted in 500 (Server Error); invoking error handler
2018-04-10 11:48:00,954 11957 [http-nio-9080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> com.project.controller.ProjectController.updateProject(java.lang.String,com.model.project.ProjectMetadata) throws org.json.JSONException]: org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Server Error
2018-04-10 11:48:00,958 11961 [http-nio-9080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> com.project.controller.ProjectController.updateProject(java.lang.String,com.model.project.ProjectMetadata) throws org.json.JSONException]: org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Server Error
2018-04-10 11:48:00,958 11961 [http-nio-9080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> com.project.controller.ProjectController.updateProject(java.lang.String,com.model.project.ProjectMetadata) throws org.json.JSONException]: org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Server Error
2018-04-10 11:48:00,962 11965 [http-nio-9080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Could not complete request
org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Server Error
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:79)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:730)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:602)
    at com.project.controller.ProjectController.updateProject(ProjectController.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:892)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:664)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2018-04-10 11:48:00,962 11965 [http-nio-9080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter - Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@440e2d74
2018-04-10 11:48:00,966 11969 [http-nio-9080-exec-1] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Server Error] with root cause
org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Server Error
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:79)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:730)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:602)
    at com.project.controller.ProjectController.updateProject(ProjectController.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:892)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:664)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2018-04-10 11:48:00,970 11973 [http-nio-9080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing PUT request for [/error]
2018-04-10 11:48:00,970 11973 [http-nio-9080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /error
2018-04-10 11:48:00,974 11977 [http-nio-9080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
2018-04-10 11:48:00,974 11977 [http-nio-9080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'basicErrorController'
2018-04-10 11:48:01,006 12009 [http-nio-9080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor - Written [{timestamp=Tue Apr 10 11:48:00 IST 2018, status=500, error=Internal Server Error, message=500 Server Error, path=/rfi/api/di/v1/app/abcde/metadata/}] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@4e9658b5]
2018-04-10 11:48:01,006 12009 [http-nio-9080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2018-04-10 11:48:01,006 12009 [http-nio-9080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

*What is causing this error?Plase help*

[request and response image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlAW6.png)

[headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4kXG.png)

[request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Agszb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is not linked to your code. 
The 500 error is returned from the external service your are calling. 
Try to call your external service using another client like postman to be sure the service works the way you are using it .

Based on the conversation we had in the comments. 
The only thing that is different between your code and the screenshot of your request via postman is the missing `s` in "tags" (in the code in your question you wrote "tag" instead of "tags")

Comment: thanks for the response,i tried same with external service using postman and i got my metadata updated..so there is no problem with he external service i hope...



but from my rest url locally i am getting below response:
{
    "timestamp": "2018-04-10T08:30:05.818+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "500 Server Error",
    "path": "/rfi/api/di/v1/app/abcde/metadata"
}
i am struggling with this since yesterday..

Comment: Do you have access to the external services logs to check what happened ? Print the JSONObject your are sending to the service and compare it with the one you used via postman. Since we don't have the server's code, we can't know what the server is expecting.

Comment: no.... :( but that is working fine there is no error in response if i hit directly their url ith same request body n headers

Comment: and the http status code is not 500 when you hit the service via postman ?

Comment: No external service is not returning 500, after hitting the URL I can see the changes which mexpecting.. there must be some issue while doing this put operation please have a look in my code

Comment: I tested your code, and it looks ok : https://gist.github.com/areguig/24c90d5aad0f7ce3596fd5945b6e9601  . It sends the input content

Comment: yes correct if you can see the error stack above it is clearly forming request without error,but failing while doing PUT operation:2018-04-10 13:54:10,954 9274 [http-nio-9080-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.web.client.RestTemplate - PUT request for "http://<>/public/api/projects/abcde/metadata/" resulted in 500 (Server Error); invoking error handler

Comment: This is happening on the external server, without the logs it is hard to find what is wrong. Are you sending the exact same headers too from postman ? (same key and exactly the same value ?)

Comment: can you share a sceenshot of the postman request and response including headers?

Comment: have attached above please check and let me know if you need any other info

Comment: was talking about the postman response/request you did to the external service to test it was working fine.

Comment: added the screen,they are not returning any message but the changes are getting done in their platform

Comment: updated my answer: if this is the problem, the error handling on that service is not very good IMHO.

Comment: Thank you so much Akli, now it's working fine.wasted ur n mine time also on this stupid mistake